# Laravel - Calculations returning unexpected results with decimal/numeric data type (Postgres)

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I'm attempting to build a very simple function to convert units to/from a 'Base Unit of Measurement' (ie: various different units to/from KGs), but I'm running into some inconsistent results. When I convert a value to the Base UOM I get the expected value; however, when I convert it *back*, I'm getting a result that does not match my expectations.

I'm currently using the `decimal` (numeric) data type, on my Postgres database, but if I convert the `quantity` column to `float`, the outcome is inline with what I'm expecting.

### Migrations

#### conversions_table

```
$table->decimal('lb', 18, 16, true);
// value = 0.4535923700000000
```

#### consumtion_table

```
$table->decimal('quantity', 16, 10);
```

### Code

```
// Convert LBs to KG
$quantity * $conversions->lb

// Convert KGs to LBs
$quantity / $conversions->lb
```

### Example

If a $value = 0.125 is converted to KGs it results in the function returning `0.0566990463` KGs; therefore, when I run the function in the reverse direction to return the value in KGs back to LBs, it results in `0.12500000011023113`

But, if I change the data type to `float()`, that same function returns `0.05669904625` KGs, which then returns the expected result when converting *back* to LBs -> `0.125`.

### Summary

I'm sure this is a 'newbie' mistake and perhaps expected behaviour due to a misunderstanding of these different data types, but I'd be very thankful if someone could clarify what the best approach is tackling this kind of scenario!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined your column `consumption.quantity` as:

```
$table->decimal('quantity', 16, 10);
```

That's a `numeric` with a *precision* of 16 and a ***scale*** of 10. I.e. 10 fractional decimal digits.

The result of `0.125 * 0.45359237` is **`0.05669904625`**, which requires 11 fractional decimal digits to be represented *exactly*. Since your column only allows 10, the value is rounded to `0.0566990463`, thereby introducing the error. (Or there are additional links in the food chain that (also) round to a scale of 10.)

[Current Lavarel documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations)
Quoting the [current Postgres manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)

> If the scale of a value to be stored is greater than the declared scale of the column, the system will round the value to the specified number of fractional digits.

Solution: Allow more fractional digits. Example with a scale of 16 in your table columns:

```
$table->decimal('quantity', 20, 16);
```

Or drop maximum precision and scale altogether and use plain `numeric`. Or whatever suits your needs.

To be precise, this is slightly incorrect:

> If a $value = 0.125 is converted to KGs it results in the function returning 0.0566990463 KGs;

The calculation should return the exact number. It is later rounded to a scale of 10.

Comment: After all that, it was simply a problem with basic arithmetic. It doesn't look as though Laravel currently has a way of defining just a plain `numeric` column type so I'll take the approach of adding more fractional digits. Thanks.